# Android RecyclerView after scrolling vertical showing last loaded images before load new content?

Tags: android

I have a recyclerview showing list of images(download from API).when I scroll the view it first show the last loaded images and then load the new content.I don't want to show last loaded content again and again on scroll.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ProductItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ProductItem item = dataSet.get(position);

    String url = new ApiCalls(holder.photo.getContext()).getBaseUrl() + item.getImages().getImageUrl().get(0);

    //to do


    new ImageViewLoader(taskObserver, holder.photo, url)
            .setDesiredRatio(1.0f)
            .setFallback(R.drawable.img_default_phone)
            .load();

    String percentage = item.getSalePercentage();
    if (percentage != null && !percentage.isEmpty()) {
        holder.badge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.badge.setText(percentage);
    } else if (item.isNew()) {
        holder.badge.setText(holder.badge.getContext().getString(R.string.product_grid_item_badge_new));
    } else {
        holder.badge.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    holder.productName.setText(item.getProductName());

    String salePrice = item.getSalePrice();
    if (salePrice != null && !salePrice.isEmpty()) {
        holder.price.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.price.setText(formatPrice(item.getCurrency(), item.getPrice()));
        holder.price.setPaintFlags(holder.price.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

        holder.salePrice.setText(formatPrice(item.getCurrency(), salePrice));
        holder.salePrice.setTextColor(holder.salePrice.getContext().getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.red_100));
    } else {
        holder.price.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.salePrice.setText(formatPrice(item.getCurrency(), item.getPrice()));
        holder.salePrice.setTextColor(holder.salePrice.getContext().getResources()
                .getColor(android.R.color.black));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "it first show the last loaded images and then load the new content.", but I have two guesses:

1. Since the parameter into onBindViewHolder is often a recycled view holder, it's state is kept as it is scrolled out of view. That means new items contain the the images & text of the recycled items unless you re-set them in onBindViewHolder.
2. The ImageViewLoader which we don't see any source for, does it cancel the ongoing request if a new one is submitted for the same view holder? The effect you are seeing could be that the loader for the old image is still trying to download the image, but completes later on when the item has already been recycled.

Answer (score 0):

Use `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(dataSet.size()-1);`